# Get requested URL in jsp

Tags: jsp

jsp` I would like to know my request url, but I tried this and it doesnt work to me

```
<script>
    $url = getRequestURL();
    .....
```

So I am wondering what's the way to get the url?

btw I didnt actually learn jsp so not sure where to look for reference, is this script called jsp script or anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) print it as if it's a JavaScript variable as follows:

```
<script>
    var url = '${pageContext.request.requestURL}';
    // ...
</script>
```

But why don't you just grab it by JavaScript API directly?

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    // ...
</script>
```

Note that this code is JavaScript, which is completely different language than Java/JSP.
As to learning JSP, start taking a look in [our JSP tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) (to get to it yourself, just put your mouse above the tag which you've put below the question yourself and then click the *info* link in the black pop box, almost every other bit self-respected tag has a wiki page like this, so has JavaScript also [one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)).